# Proving Linear Regression with Gradient Descent Converge to OLS estimates

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, convergence, gradient-descent

## Problem

I am having trouble showing that the parameters $\theta\in \mathbf{R}^{m}$ for Linear Regression converge to the classic OLS estimates using gradient descent. Please find below my attempt:

## Define Data Model

> **Number of Features**: $m$
>
> **Sample Size**: $n$
>
> **Data**: $X\in\mathbf{R}^{n\times m}$
>
> **Continuous Labels**: $y\in\mathbf{R}^{n}$
>
> **Linear Model**: $h(\theta, X) = X\cdot\theta$
>
> **Mean Squared Error Cost Function**: $J(h(\theta, X), y) = \frac{1}{m}(h(\theta, X)-y)^T(h(\theta, X)-y)$
>
> **Ordinary Least Squares Estimator**: $\hat{\theta}_{OLS} = (X^TX)^{-1}(X^Ty)$

## Gradient Descent Algorithm

> 1. Let $\alpha\in(0,1)$ be the learning-rate hyperparameter.
> 2. Define $\{\hat{\theta}^{(0)},\dots,\hat{\theta}^{(k)}\}$ as the sequence of estimated values of $\theta$ after $k$-iterations
> 3. Fix $\hat{\theta}^{(0)}$ to be some constant vector.
> 4. $\hat{\theta}^{(k+1)}:=\hat{\theta}^{(k)}-\alpha\nabla_\theta J(h(\hat{\theta}^{(k)}, X), y)$

## Compute Model Specific Learning Rule

The gradient of the MSE is:
$$
\nabla_\theta J(h(\theta, X), y) = \frac{2}{m}X^T(h(\theta, X)-y)
$$
Plugging in our linear model hypothesis, we obtain:
$$
\nabla_\theta J(h(\theta, X), y) = \frac{2}{m}(X^TX\cdot\theta-X^Ty)
$$
Thus, by substituting the above expression into step (4) of the G.D. algorithm, our model specific learning rule becomes:
$$
\hat{\theta}^{(k+1)}:=(I_m-\frac{2\alpha}{m}X^TX)\cdot\hat{\theta}^{(k)}+\frac{2\alpha}{m}X^Ty
$$

## Convert Recursive Learning Rule into Explicit Form

Let us make the following simplifications:
\begin{align}
A & = I_m-\frac{2\alpha}{m}X^TX \\
v & = \frac{2\alpha}{m}X^Ty
\end{align}
Then, we get:
$$
\hat{\theta}^{(k+1)}:=A\cdot\hat{\theta}^{(k)}+v
$$
We attempt to find an explicit form by inspecting the first few terms of the sequence:
\begin{align}
\hat{\theta}^{(1)} &= A\cdot\hat{\theta}^{(0)}+v=A\cdot\hat{\theta}^{(0)}+I_mv \\
\hat{\theta}^{(2)} &= A\cdot\hat{\theta}^{(1)}+v=A^2\cdot\hat{\theta}^{(0)}+Av+I_mv \\
\hat{\theta}^{(3)} &= A\cdot\hat{\theta}^{(2)}+v=A^3\cdot\hat{\theta}^{(0)}+A^2v+Av+I_mv \\
\vdots \\
\hat{\theta}^{(k)} &= A\cdot\hat{\theta}^{(k-1)}+v=A^k\cdot\hat{\theta}^{(0)}+A^{k-1}v+\dots+A^2v+Av+I_mv \\
\end{align}
The explicit form of the learning rule is:
$$
\hat{\theta}^{(k)} = A^k\cdot\hat{\theta}^{(0)}+(\sum_{t=0}^{k-1} A^t)\cdot{v} \\
$$
**I do not know if the geometric sum formula applies for matrices**, but below is my claim (without proof):
$$
\sum_{t=0}^{k-1} A^t = (I_m-A)^{-1}(I_m-A^k)\tag{A1}
$$
The explicit form of the learning rule now becomes:
\begin{align}
\hat{\theta}^{(k)} &= A^k\cdot\hat{\theta}^{(0)}+(I_m-A)^{-1}(I_m-A^k)\cdot{v} \\
\hat{\theta}^{(k)} &= A^k\cdot\hat{\theta}^{(0)}+(I_m-A)^{-1}(v-A^kv) \\
\hat{\theta}^{(k)} &= A^k\cdot\hat{\theta}^{(0)}+(I_m-A)^{-1}v-(I_m-A)^{-1}A^kv \\
\hat{\theta}^{(k)} &= A^k\cdot\hat{\theta}^{(0)}+(\frac{2\alpha}{m}X^TX)^{-1}(\frac{2\alpha}{m}X^Ty) - (\frac{2\alpha}{m}X^TX)^{-1}A^k(\frac{2\alpha}{m}X^Ty)\\
\hat{\theta}^{(k)} &= A^k\cdot\hat{\theta}^{(0)}+(X^TX)^{-1}(X^Ty) - (X^TX)^{-1}A^k(X^Ty)\\
\end{align}
Finally, we can write our simplified explicit Gradient Descent formula as:
$$
\hat{\theta}^{(k)} = \hat{\theta}_{OLS} + A^k\cdot\hat{\theta}^{(0)} - 
 (X^TX)^{-1}A^k(X^Ty)
$$

## Next Steps

This is the part where I am stuck. By the above equation, it seems that if we show $\lim_{k\to\infty}A^k=\mathbf{0}_{m\times m}$ then $\hat{\theta}^{(k)}\rightarrow\hat{\theta}_{OLS}$. But in order to compute $A^k$, the only way I can think of is diagonalizing $A$. And since $A$ is a real, symmetric matrix, it must have real eigenvalues, with orthogonal eigenvectors (for distinct eigenvalues). We begin by finding the eigenvalues:
\begin{align}
A-\lambda I_m &= (1-\lambda)I_m - \frac{2\alpha}{m}X^TX \\
A-\lambda I_m &=
\begin{pmatrix}
1-\lambda-\frac{2\alpha}{m}\sum_{i=1}^n X_{i,1}^2 & \frac{-2\alpha}{m}\sum_{i=1}^n X_{i,1}X_{i,2} &\dots&\frac{-2\alpha}{m}\sum_{i=1}^n X_{i,1}X_{i,m} \\
 & 1-\lambda-\frac{2\alpha}{m}\sum_{i=1}^n X_{i,2}^2 &\dots& \frac{-2\alpha}{m}\sum_{i=1}^n X_{i,2}X_{i,m} \\
 & &\ddots&\vdots \\
 & & & 1-\lambda-\frac{2\alpha}{m}\sum_{i=1}^n X_{i,m}^2
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
**How can I find a closed form for the determinant of this symmetric matrix, let alone find $\lambda$ such that** $det(A-\lambda I_m)=0$?

---

Let us assume the pairs of eigenvalues & eigenvectors are $\{(\lambda_1,\vec\nu_1),\dots,(\lambda_m,\vec\nu_m)\}$. So the eigenspace can be defined as:
$$
P = (\vec\nu_1,\dots,\vec\nu_m)
$$
But since $A$ is real & symmetric, $P$ must be orthogonal, so $P^{-1}=P^T$. We can also define the Diagonalized matrix $D$ as follows:
$$
D=
\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda_1 & & \huge0 & \\
 & \lambda_2 & & \\
 & & \ddots & \\
 & \huge0 & & \lambda_m
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Then, by decomposition, we have:
$$
A = P^{-1}DP
$$
Exponentiating $A$ becomes a trivial task as we can now calculate it as such:
\begin{align}
A^k &= (P^{-1}DP)^k \\
A^k &= (P^{-1}DP)\cdot(P^{-1}DP)\cdot\dots\cdot(P^{-1}DP) \\
A^k &= P^{-1}D^kP \\
A^k &= P^TD^kP \\
A^k &= P^T\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda_1^k & & \huge0 & \\
 & \lambda_2^k & & \\
 & & \ddots & \\
 & \huge0 & & \lambda_m^k
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot P
\end{align}
Can we conclude that:
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty}A^k=\mathbf{0}_{m\times m} \Longleftrightarrow |\lambda_j| < 1, \forall j=1,\dots,m.
$$
???